# Database proc fails, saying it failed to convert a varchar(param) to int

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures

I have the following procedure which is supposed to insert a cell in a many to many table. The problem it it fails, with an error message which I do not get where it is caused, since I do not intend to do any conversion.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[updateGrade] 
    @grade int, 
    @studentName nvarchar(50), 
    @courseName nvarchar(50)
AS
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    BEGIN TRY
            IF (@grade < 0 OR @grade > 10 OR @grade=NULL )
                 RAISERROR('!! grade -- @grade < 0 OR @grade > 10 OR ISNULL(@grade, 0) = 0', 18, 0)
            IF (@studentName = '' OR ISNULL(@studentName,0) = 0)
                 RAISERROR('!! studentName -- @studentName = '' OR ISNULL(@studentName)', 18, 0)        
            IF (@courseName = '' OR ISNULL(@courseName,0) = 0)
                 RAISERROR('!! courseName -- @courseName = '' OR ISNULL(@studentName)', 18, 0)

        SET @studID = (SELECT id FROM students WHERE students.name = @studentName)
        SET @courseID = (SELECT id FROM courses WHERE courses.name = @courseName)

        INSERT INTO grades (grade, studentID, courseID)
            VALUES (@grade, @studID, @courseID)
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            SELECT 
                ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
                ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
                ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
                ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
                ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
                ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;

            IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
                ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        END CATCH;

        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
            COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

params:

```
params: 6 / Maier Bogdan / baze2
```

ret code:

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[updateGrade]
        @grade = 6,
        @studentName = N'Maier Bogdan',
        @courseName = N'baze2'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

Error:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Maier Bogdan' to data type int.

Comment: please show us the call, with parameters that generates this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error is here:

```
ISNULL(@studentName,0) = 0
```

Comparing @studentName (nvarchar(50)) to 0 (int)

Notice that **when @studentName is Null the problem not appear** because you compare 0 to 0, but, **when @studentName is not null you are comparing @studentName to 0!**

Comment: @BogdanM.: So the solution would be to use something like this: `ISNULL(@StudentName, N'') = N''` instead - use `nvarchar(n)` values - not `0` !

Comment: Thank you, i have used a rudimentary approch  @studentName = '', and it works, altoght thank you for the better solution

Comment: @marc_s, yes!  I forgot the solution! Thanks to you to post it!